# Returning a method for a form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a form which after clicking Submit should call the AddProduct method

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddProduct", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
```

The problem is the controller. Has a specified Route.

In this situation, when I click Submit, AddProduct is not called, but Index

HomeController

```
[Route("{name?}/{adminCode?}")]
public IActionResult Index(string name, string adminCode)

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddProduct(string productName)
```

How to call the AddProduct method correctly?

Comment: but the route is on an Action; Index. That's not a controller.

Comment: @JerdineSabio If index does not have a specific `Route` specified, `AddProduct` works. When I added `Route`, `AddProduct` is not called anymore

Comment: what error is showing when you submit the form?

Comment: @JerdineSabio There is no error. After clicking submit, there is URl: https://localhost:port/Home/AddProduct and the `Index` function is called.

Comment: please put your full controller code

Comment: also your view code which contains the form

Answer (score 0):

Because of the optional route parameters and the lack of a HTTP Verb on the Index action you most are most likely encountering a route conflict.

First option would be to use the appropriate route attribute on the action.

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public HomeController {

    [HttpGet("{name?}/{adminCode?}")]
    public IActionResult Index(string name, string adminCode) {
        //...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddProduct(string productName) {
        //...
    }
    
}
```

That way when the post is made it will only consider actions that can handle POST requests.

Another option I would suggest is moving `AddProduct` to a separate controller (like ProductController).

HomeController

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public HomeController {

    [HttpGet("{name?}/{adminCode?}")]
    public IActionResult Index(string name, string adminCode) {
        //...
    }
    
}
```

ProductController

```
[Route("[controller]")]
ProductController {

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddProduct(string productName) {
        //...
    }
}
```

and updating the view accordingly

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddProduct", "Product", FormMethod.Post))
```

Apart from that, there is not enough details about what you are actually trying to achieve here, so I would also suggest adding more details about the main goals so that a more target answer can be provided.

Answer (score -2):

Because of a wrong route config, controller can't see you that you have AddProduct action, and uses default Index action  with AddProduct
as a name parameter. So try to add  a route to AddProduct too

```
[Route("~/Home/AddProduct")]
public ActionResult AddProduct(string productName)
```

if  the problem continues with another actions. Pls post your controller header and config routes code. Probably it needs to be fixed.